# uWSGI fails to build from pip on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, uwsgi

trying to install uWSGI from the command line

```
pip install uwsgi
```

results in a long stack trace, here is the end of it:

```
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.a(parser.o):
 relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a PIE object; 
recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** error linking uWSGI ***

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/user/venv/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-ve0nx9k8/uwsgi/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-l_7f937a/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/user/venv/include/site/python3.6/uwsgi" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-ve0nx9k8/uwsgi/
```

I'm using Python 3.6. Python 2 works and Python 3.7 works, but unfortunately I need to use Python 3.6. There is nothing else in the virtual environment, and this is a pretty new reinstall of ubuntu.

Comment: I found this and it looks like there isn't a solution in a venv. https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/1770

Comment: @leech, which uWSGI version are you trying to install?

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the linker wants to build a **P**osition **I**ndependent **E**xecutable (PIE object), but it can't because the library `libpython3.6m.a` was built without the support of this kind of linking.

I faced this issue when using Python installed via `pyenv`.

To fix the issue in this case, reinstall Python with special compiler flags:

```
CONFIGURE_OPTS=--enable-shared pyenv install 3.7.7  # use your Python version
```

This is mentioned in their [wiki](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#how-to-build-cpython-with---enable-shared), but for me, it was unclear when such flag is required.

Answer (score -2):

I had this error trying to build with the system python. When I switched to [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) and installed a custom python version uWSGI installed fine.